# Data routing over internet and p2p network

Tags: internet, p2p

I have couple of questions over data routing over a network:

1. The data from one user to another over internet through interconnected routers.I wanted to know are these routers connected to central router which guides them decide the routing path? In other words is basic Internet topology centralised or decentralised?
2. I understand peer to peer protocol is basically decentralised? How is it different from Internet protocol if Internet is also something decentralised.
3. In peer to peer protocol data is routed through chain of interconnected system. How would data be routed if one system in chain is corrupted if the topology is not centrally administered?

Comment: There are dozen of different p2p networks, about which one are you talking?

Comment: Peer to peer file sharing